# Will the Android SDK alone support my needs to create this App?

Tags: android

I am going to be creating an app for school. The main question is, does the android SDK have the tools that make features of this happen?

Here are the thing that I need to happen:

1. I need the ability to have a picture selected from the SD card and displayed on the screen through the application and not the gallery.
2. I need to be able to have 2 people with the app be able to display stuff to each other. For example, I need 1 person with the app able to be able to select and order a playlist of songs and the other person needs to be able to see that order.
3. Can i download images to the app through some type of server (I have no idea how I would do a server so please explain if you can)

Would I need some sort of engine to do this?

Number two I'm not that concerned about, but I NEED to know if I can do number 1

Comment: You won't need an engine, but there are likely libraries you are going to want to look into. This is a pretty tall order, attempting to manage another phone is likely going to run into tons of security issues.

Comment: Yes, you can do n.1 just using SDK. Actually, it's pretty simple...

Comment: Just to make sure, Can i display the image through the application and not the gallery?